# Marker animation not working using animateMarkerToCoordinate android

Tags: react-native, google-maps

When I use below code and generate release version, my app is getting crash.

```
this.marker._component.animateMarkerToCoordinate(
            newCoordinate,
            duration
          );
```

and when I use

```
userCoordinate.timing({newUserCoordinate, duration}).start();
```

the marker movement is not smooth, it jumps from one coordinate to another.

Please provide me solution.

Comment: Would you be able to provide us with a **[Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**?

Comment: This is the common code which is used by most of the people but need help why is it crashing on release mode.